# How to packing the results of List.ForEach() to a new list?

Tags: c#, linq, list

I'm learning C#.

I have two lists of same type.

```
struct Foo
{
    string fKey;
    Bar bVal;
}
List<Foo> f1; List<Foo> f2;
```

Now f1 and f2 contains same number of elements, with each fKey in f1 present in f2 also, but in a different position.

What I want to do is to join these two lists on the fKey, do some operation on the Bar values (some kind of merging), and store the results to a new List.

```
Foo Merge(Foo f1, Foo f2)
{
// Merge
    return new Foo(f1);
}
```

For this I have reached until here.

```
f1.Join(f2, oldFoo => oldFoo.fKey, newFoo => newFoo.fKey, (oldFoo, newFoo) => new { myOldFoo = oldFoo, myNewFoo = newFoo } //  Join on the fKey attribute
                        ).ToList().         //  Dump the results to a list
                            ForEach(aPair => Merge(aPair.myNewFoo, aPair.myOldFoo));
```

In the imperative programming, I would push the return value of Merge() to a new List. 
How I can do that in this consruct?

Comment: Does Merge return a value?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Perform your `Merge` operation within a `Select` projection, then use `ToList` to materialize the results into a list.

```
var l = f1.Join(f2, oldFoo => oldFoo.fKey, newFoo => newFoo.fKey, 
                    (oldFoo, newFoo) => new { myOldFoo = oldFoo, myNewFoo = newFoo })
          .Select(aPair => Merge(aPair.myNewFoo, aPair.myOldFoo))
          .ToList();
```

**Edit**: I assume you could combine the `Merge` into the `Join` for conciseness:

```
var l = f1.Join(f2, oldFoo => oldFoo.fKey, newFoo => newFoo.fKey, 
                    (oldFoo, newFoo) => Merge(newFoo, oldFoo))
          .ToList();
```

Comment: Yet another testament to the dangers of ForEach

Comment: Indeed - note the lack of using `List.ForEach` at all here, which is great given that the nature of the operation doesn't lend itself to `ForEach` in the first place.

Comment: Thanks, Douglas. The second one is much simpler and that works well for me.

Answer (score 1):

That's exactly what the `ConvertAll()` function does.